# How to make multiple dependent dropdown inputs more efficient?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I managed to make dependent dropdown list using codes from https://codewithcurt.com/create-dependent-drop-down-on-google-web-app/. I need to make multiple entries of the same questions like in the pic here:

[image]

It works and I get the intended responses. But it seems like the trigger function can only be used once. I meant, when I tried to use GetIslands(this.value) for the second line of entries, it didn't work. Here's how it's like when I tried to use GetIslands(this.value) repeatedly:
[image]

The dropdown list of islands for Person A was changed when I selected a state for Person B.

So I had to repeat the same block of codes multiple times (hence GetIslands2(this.value) for the second entry). There must be a less redundant way to do it. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

HTML & JAVASCRIPT

```
<label>State</label>
      <select id="state1" onchange="GetIslands(this.value)" required></div>
      <option value="" hidden>Select a state</option>
      <? for(var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) { ?>      
      <option value="<?= states[i] ?>" ><?= states[i] ?></option>
      <? } ?></select>

<label>Island</label>
    <select name="island" id="island1" required>
    <option value=""  hidden>Select a marine park</option>
    </select>

<label>State</label>
  <select id="state2" onchange="GetIslands2(this.value)" required></div>
  <option value="" hidden>Select a state</option>
  <? for(var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) { ?>      
  <option value="<?= states[i] ?>" ><?= states[i] ?></option>
  <? } ?></select>

<label>Island</label>
    <select name="island2" id="island2" required>
    <option value=""  hidden>Select a marine park</option>
    </select>

<script>
function GetIslands(state)
  {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
    {
    console.log(ar);
    
    island1.length = 0;
    
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "Select an island";
    option.hidden = true;
    island1.appendChild(option);
    
    ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
    {    
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item;
      option.text = item;
      island1.appendChild(option);    
    });
    
    }).getIslands(state);
  };

function GetIslands2(state)
  {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
    {
    console.log(ar);
    
    island2.length = 0;
    
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "Select an island";
    option.hidden = true;
    island2.appendChild(option);
    
    ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
    {    
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item;
      option.text = item;
      island2.appendChild(option);    
    });
    
    }).getIslands(state);
  };
</script>
```

APPS SCRIPT

```
function getState() { 
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var siteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sites"); 
  var getLastRow = siteSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
      if(return_array.indexOf(siteSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue()) === -1) {
        return_array.push(siteSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue());
      }
  }
  return return_array;  
}

function getIslands(state) { 
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var siteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sites"); 
  var getLastRow = siteSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
      if(siteSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() === state){
        return_array.push(siteSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue());
      }
  }
  const unique = (value,index,self) => {return self.indexOf(value) ===index;}
  var Unique_List=return_array.filter(unique); 
  return Unique_List;  
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. unfortunately, I cannot understand `(i.e. 1st line: State: (dropdown) Island: (dropdown) 2nd line: State: (dropdown) Island: (dropdown)`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: Thank you for reminding, I just edited the picture in. Do let me know if I still didn't make it clear

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. Is your added image the sample input situation?

Comment: Yes, and I added the sample response in Google Sheet. Basically, the web app does what I wanted, but the codes are very redundant.

Comment: here is a sample spreadsheet created specifically for this question, If you paste some sample data there pertinent to your example I can show you how to code the dependent dropdown a bit more efficiently.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Gkl99OzTk51E_ftUb32GdHG0aK4ZBdb683tLZcmebs/edit

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand `Then I should receive input like this:`. And also, when I saw your updated script, I think that an error occurs at `<select name="island" id="island1"" required>` and `<select name="island" id="island2"" required>`. So, I cannot still understand your current issue. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Thank you for pointing the error out. Did you mean it should be <select name="island1" id="island1"" required> and <select name="island2" id="island2"" required> ? It was a mistake and I changed it. But it didn't affect the outcome.  My goal is to create a registration form for multiple people to fill in at once. The questions for each person are identical. I mean, Person A will be asked for state and island, Person B, C and so on will be asked for state and island too.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Did you mean it should be <select name="island1" id="island1"" required> and <select name="island2" id="island2"" required> ?`, no. I thought that for example, in the case of `"island1""` of `<select name="island1" id="island1"" required>`, I think that one `"` is required to be remove. But, from your question, you say the script works. So I'm worried that your showing script is different from your tested script. But, I would like to support you. So, when I could correctly understand your question, I would like to try to think of a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. That is the original script, but you are right, I changed it a bit when I posted the codes here. There's supposed to be a third dependent dropdown list, the Location in each specified island. But I removed it here for the sake of simplicity, as it is similar to the first two dropdown lists. The rest are identical to my tested script. I think I know the problem, which is that in GetIslands() function, I specified the ID, island1. But I don't know how to make the script know when to change to island2. Hence I created the GetIslands2() function for island2.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm your current issue. In your showing HTML, there are 4 dropdown lists (`state1, island1, state2, island2`). When `state1` is changed, a value is set to `island1`. But, when `state2` is changed, the value of `island1` is changed. But, in this case, you want to change the value of `island2`. Is my understanding correct? And, in your situation, you are testing the different scripts from your showing script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thank you for replying, you are right, there are 4 dropdown lists. This showing script is a bit different from my testing script, which has more dropdown lists. The apps script is the same. And you are right that when `state1` is changed, a corresponding island list is set to `island1`. For my current script (both testing and showing), this happens to `state2` and `island2` too. The problem is that I had to create two trigger functions, `GetIslands()` and `GetIslands2()`, which are practically the same, except for the IDs of the island dropdown (island1, island2). I'd like to merge them in one

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested your showing script, when `state1` is changed, a value is set to `island1`. And, when `state2` is changed, a value is set to `island2`. In your showing script, it seems that your goal is achieved. But, in your goal, you want to achieve this situation using only the function `GetIslands`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thank you for replying, Yes, I'd like to find a way to make it less redundant, like using just one function, `GetIslands()`

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I thought that I could understand your question. So, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? This proposed script is for your showing script. So, please test my proposed script to your showing script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When `state1` is changed, a value is set to `island1`. And, when `state2` is changed, a value is set to `island2`. In the current script, in order to achieve this, it is required to use 2 functions of `GetIslands` and `GetIslands2`.
- In your goal, you want to achieve this situation using only the function `GetIslands`.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your showing HTML is modified as follows.

```html
<label>State</label>
<select id="state1" onchange="GetIslands(this)" required></div>
<option value="" hidden>Select a state</option>
<? for(var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) { ?>      
<option value="<?= states[i] ?>" ><?= states[i] ?></option>
<? } ?></select>

<label>Island</label>
<select name="island" id="island1" required>
<option value=""  hidden>Select a marine park</option>
</select>

<label>State</label>
<select id="state2" onchange="GetIslands(this)" required></div>
<option value="" hidden>Select a state</option>
<? for(var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) { ?>      
<option value="<?= states[i] ?>" ><?= states[i] ?></option>
<? } ?></select>

<label>Island</label>
<select name="island2" id="island2" required>
<option value=""  hidden>Select a marine park</option>
</select>

<script>
function GetIslands(e) {
  const obj = {state1: island1, state2: island2};
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (ar) {
    console.log(ar);
    obj[e.id].length = 0;
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "Select an island";
    option.hidden = true;
    obj[e.id].appendChild(option);
    ar.forEach(function (item, index) {
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item;
      option.text = item;
      obj[e.id].appendChild(option);
    });
  }).getIslands(e.value);
}
</script>
```

- In this modification, an object for converting the edited tag is prepared like `const obj = {state1: island1, state2: island2}`. And, using this, each tag is managed.

Comment: @LauraEverdeen Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question and think of the solution with your cooperation. Thank you, too.